# Why does Github actions: upload-release-asset@v1 fail finding the generated assets?

Tags: github-actions

repo:
https://github.com/nofishonfriday/pamplejuce

contained workflow .yml:
https://github.com/nofishonfriday/pamplejuce/blob/main/.github/workflows/cmake_ctest.yml

I copy the relevant part here:

```
release:
if: contains(github.ref, 'tags/v')
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
needs: build_and_test
outputs: 
    upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}

steps:
- name: Create Release
  id: create_release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  with:
    tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
    release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
    draft: false
    prerelease: false

- name: Download All Artifacts
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v2

- name: Upload Windows Asset
  uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  with:
    upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
    asset_path: ./${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}-Windows.zip
    asset_name: ${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}-Windows.zip
    asset_content_type: application/zip

- name: Upload Linux Asset
  uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  with:
    upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
    asset_path: ./${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}-Linux.zip
    asset_name: ${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}-Linux.zip
    asset_content_type: application/zip

- name: Upload MacOS Asset
  uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  with:
    upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
    asset_path: ./${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}-MacOS.zip
    asset_name: ${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}-MacOS.zip
    asset_content_type: application/zip
```

The release job fails with `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './Pamplejuce-Windows.zip'` although I can see the generated artifact with this name:
https://github.com/nofishonfriday/pamplejuce/actions/runs/2599795517

How do I fix this?

Comment: The created artifacts don't have .zip in their path name, as you can check on the [workflow_run summary](https://github.com/nofishonfriday/pamplejuce/actions/runs/2599795517). Did you try removing the `.zip` suffix for each upload step to see if it finds the artifact?

Comment: This sounded like a good hint, thanks, but when I do `asset_path: ./${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}-Windows` (leaving out the `.zip`) I get `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having trouble getting an the upload action to run on a file that 100% exists, as I'm able to verify with `ls` that it's exactly where I expect and is called what I expect it to be called. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Ethan No, sorry, I gave up (for now) and add the builds manually to GiHub releases.

Comment: I figured it out in my case. For me it was that the action seems to always run from a root context regardless of how you have your environment setup. I was using with cache-dependancy-path to run my steps and when I tested with ls in later steps the cwd was the child folder where the package.json was located so I thought it would continue down. I had to use the relative path from the <root>/ of the repository, not from the cwd, then it worked.